# How to eliminate certain values in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get a sum of transactions within the last 30 days. But, I also need to be sure there have no #KYC:Pass comments on the accounts as well.

I'm in Snowflake and I've tried running various subqueries and joins. I'm officially stuck.

```
SELECT SUM(amount_base_unit) as GPV, p.unit_token FROM PAYMENTS_DW.PUBLIC.PAYMENT_TRANSACTIONS as p
WHERE country_code='US'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT c.target_token FROM REGULATOR.RAW_OLTP.COMMENTS as c
    WHERE c.text ILIKE '%#KYC:Pass%'
    and c.updated_at < '2019-10-11'
)
AND is_GPV='1'
AND PAYMENT_TRX_RECOGNIZED_AT BETWEEN dateadd(month,-3,current_timestamp()) AND dateadd(month,0,current_timestamp())
GROUP BY unit_token
HAVING SUM(amount_base_unit) >= 10000000
LIMIT 5
;
```

It's not returning any rows (which I know isn't correct). Any ideas, folks?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I switched the query up to see what was going wrong, and it looks like the subquery is the culprit. The NOT ILIKE KYC:Pass filter works until I throw in the aggregate subquery to sum up the transactions.

```
FROM REGULATOR.RAW_OLTP.CASES c 
JOIN REGULATOR.RAW_OLTP.AUDIT_LOGS ral
  ON ral.case_id = c.id
WHERE ral.comment not ilike '%#KYC:Pass%'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT SUM(p.amount_base_unit) FROM PAYMENTS_DW.PUBLIC.PAYMENT_TRANSACTIONS as p
    WHERE p.country_code ='US'
    AND p.is_GPV='1'
    AND p.PAYMENT_TRX_RECOGNIZED_AT BETWEEN dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp()) AND dateadd(month,0,current_timestamp())
    GROUP BY p.unit_token
  HAVING SUM(p.amount_base_unit) >= 10000000)
  LIMIT 5
  ;
```

So, closer, I think?

Comment: I suspect that upwards of 80% of this community is 'self-taught'. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

This subquery:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.target_token
            FROM REGULATOR.RAW_OLTP.COMMENTS as c
            WHERE c.text ILIKE '%#KYC:Pass%' AND
                  c.updated_at < '2019-10-11'
           )
```

is not correlated to the outer query.  Hence, it returns either true or false for *all* rows.  I speculate that you want a correlation clause.  I don't know exactly what, but perhaps:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM REGULATOR.RAW_OLTP.COMMENTS c
            WHERE c.target_token = p.unit_token AND
                  c.text ILIKE '%#KYC:Pass%' AND
                  c.updated_at < '2019-10-11'
           )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately it's still returning that darn KYCPass comment. I hope I'm explaining this all correctly. I'm new to this and self-taught.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly `LIKE '%#KYC:Pass%'` or can you change it to `LIKE '%KYC%Pass%'`?

Comment: @SirKefka . . . Does a query filtering on `c.text ILIKE '%#KYC:Pass%' AND c.updated_at < '2019-10-11'` return anything?

Comment: it does. It looks like the aggregate functions is what's screwing this up. I switched the query order up a bit as an experiment:

Answer (score 0):

Taking Gordon's point of the NOT EXISTS needing to be correlated into account, and snowflake sometimes acting strange of correlated sub-queries.

Would switching to a CTE and checking for a failed LEFT JOIN via the IS NULL help?

```
WITH kyc_pass_com AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT target_token
        FROM REGULATOR.RAW_OLTP.COMMENTS 
        WHERE text ILIKE '%#KYC:Pass%' 
            AND updated_at < '2019-10-11'
)
SELECT SUM(amount_base_unit) as GPV
    ,p.unit_token
FROM PAYMENTS_DW.PUBLIC.PAYMENT_TRANSACTIONS AS p
LEFT JOIN kyc_pass_com AS c
    ON c.target_token = p.unit_token
WHERE p.country_code='US'
    AND c.target_token IS NULL
    AND is_GPV='1'
    AND PAYMENT_TRX_RECOGNIZED_AT BETWEEN dateadd(month,-3,current_timestamp()) AND current_timestamp()
GROUP BY unit_token
HAVING SUM(amount_base_unit) >= 10000000
LIMIT 5;
```